# Passing a variable to a child function without using it as an argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a parent function in Python which calls a child function. I want to be able to define a variable in the parent function which is accessible from the child, *without* having to pass it as a parameter.

The reason for this is because the function signature of the child has to remain stable in order to retain compatibility with a large amount of code. In addition, my real use-case involves large call-stacks that are potentially hundreds of function calls deep, and passing this single argument through every single function call seems painful.

What I want to do is something like this:

```py
def parent():
    context = [1]
    child(a, b, c)

def child(a, b, c):
    # Somehow access the context here, without it being an explicit argument
    context = get_context()
    context.append[5]
```

What I'm trying to recreate here is similar to [React Contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but in Python. Specifically the use-case for them is the same as what I'm after:

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

I've thought about using a context manager (`with x`), but that doesn't actually provide a mechanism of the child accessing the context. I also can't use a global variable or class variable here because I need to support multiple of these call stacks happening independently of each other.

Is this possible in Python in some way?

Comment: if you don't want to send it then keep `context` in global variable. At this moment `context` is local variable and you can't access it from other function.

Answer (score 3):

A class would seem a perfect fit to give a function “context”:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def child(self, a, b, c):
        self.context …

def parent():
    foo = Foo([1])
    fun.child(a, b, c)

    # even:
    # child = foo.child
    # child(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a default variable to your child function, and checking if the value of that variable is `None`.

example:

```
def parent():
    context = [1]
    child(a, b, c, context)

def child(a, b, c, context = None):
    if context:   
        context.append[5]
```

using a default variable as the last argument will retain compatibility with all previous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> With OOP, you can do this:

```
class ParentClass:
    context = [1,]
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def printname(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)

class Childclass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, my_context):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        ParentClass.context.append(my_context)
```

To append 5 to context and assign values to a, b, and c:

```
x = Childclass('a', 'b', 'c', 5)
print(x.a, '\n', x.b, '\n', x.c, '\n', x.context)
```

> Result

```
   a
 b
 c
 [1, 5]
```